# Set Date() to something specific while script executes

Tags: php, date, legacy

I have picked up some legacy code which uses `date()` all over the place. On the 31st of each month (if applicable) the script has a bug which I need to be able to replicate to fix. In order to do this I need the script to think that it is the 31st today.

Obviously I could parse the date and give it a string of the date that I want, but that would have to be on every instance of `date()` - which would be very difficult to change and I could miss one all to easily.

Is there a means therefore at the top of the script to specify what "Today's date" is? Or does `date()` get the date from the server each and every time, rendering this impossible?

**Edit**

For clarification this script is hosted on Azure App Services which means I can't change the time of the system unfortunately.

Comment: I think the quickest option is setting the `system date` of your server.

Comment: I need this information as well. Pretending to have another system time to the script

Comment: The library [libfaketime](https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime) might be able to help. It's a bit fiddly, but you can use it to force the date for a particular application (either Apache/nginx or PHP depending on your configuration).

Comment: Whether its possible to override date() function using override_function? let me check and will get back to you.

Comment: @Peter Unfortunately it is hosted on Azure and I don't think you can change the time of the App Services :/ (not at least as far as I have seen yet)

Comment: You can try `runkit_function_redefine`. Added it as an anwer.

Answer (score 2):

There is an outdated pecl extension called [apd](https://pecl.php.net/package/apd) which provides a function `override_function()` which does exactly what you want. Did not test it but it probably won't work anymore.

Another approach is so called monkey patching, making use of phps namespaces. See http://till.klampaeckel.de/blog/archives/105-Monkey-patching-in-PHP.html for example and explanation.

```
namespace myNameSpace;

function date($format, $timestamp = '') {
    echo 'Would have returned "' . \date($format, $timestamp) . '"';
}
echo date('d.m.Y', time());
```

As we are in namespace **\myNameSpace** php will first search for **\myNameSpace\date()** and use that instead of **\date()**.

Comment: Monkey patching is a great idea - no external dependencies etc.

Comment: Brilliant approach

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to redeclare `date` for testing purposes? Of course, PHP itself will not allow this, but you can use `runkit`'s [runkit_function_redefine()](http://php.net/runkit_function_redefine):

```
runkit_function_redefine('date','', 'return "XX-YY-ZZZZ";');
```

Just note that:

> By default, only userspace functions may be removed, renamed, or
>   modified. In order to override internal functions, you must enable the
>   runkit.internal_override setting in php.ini.

Answer (score -1):

Changing the system time is usually restricted to `root-level` accounts. `PHP` will be running under the user id of the webserver, which SHOULD NOT BE root. You'll have to use `sudo` to let the webserver run with elevated privileges for this purpose. [See this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44865/change-server-date-using-php)

Assuming the server is running on windows I believe you could do `exec('date 11/24/2013')`. If it is a linux based server I think you can do something like this: `exec('date -s "24 NOV 2013 12:38:00"').`

Command line : Linux Set Date Command Example

Use the following syntax to set new data and time:

```
date --set="STRING"
```

For example, set new data to 2 Oct 2006 18:00:00, type the following command as root user:

```
# date -s "2 OCT 2006 18:00:00"
```

OR u can also simplify format using following syntax:

```
# date +%Y%m%d -s "20081128"
```